# Заменить текст случайным словом из предложенных

Tags: python

пишу телеграм бота. В боте есть шаблоны, и я хочу добавить такую функцию, как случяайное слово при рассылке.
То есть, человек пишет:

{Привет|Как дела} Это Ваня. Ну ладно {Пока|Прощай}

Подскажите, как сделать, что бы скрипт брал рандомные слова в скобках?
Допустим так:

Привет Это Ваня. Ну ладно Прощай

Как дела Это Ваня. Ну ладно Прощай

Я пробовал использовать форматирование строк, но если пользователь введет больше 1й такой строки, то вылетит ошибка

Вот код:

```
import random


class RandomText(object):
    def __format__(self, format):
        return random.choice(format.split('|'))


print('fef fe efe {:Привет|Пока}'.format(RandomText()))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

чем не устраивает решение в лоб?

```
import random

text = f"{random.choice(['Привет', 'Как дела'])} Это Ваня. Ну ладно {random.choice(['Пока', 'Прощай'])}"
print(text)
```

ну или в вашем случае

```
text = f"{random.choice('Привет|Как дела'.split('|'))} Это Ваня. Ну ладно {random.choice('Пока|Прощай'.split('|'))}"
```

ну и можете конечно не в 1 строчку делать:

```
text1 = random.choice('Привет|Как дела'.split('|'))
text2 = random.choice('Пока|Прощай'.split('|'))
text = f"{text1} Это Ваня. Ну ладно {text2}"
```

P.S.

Понял наконец то ваш случай - вам нужны регулярные выражения

Принцип работы следующий:

1. ищем все структуры вида `{}`
2. затем последовательно парсим их, получаем случайное число и делаем замену

вот пример кода:

```
import re
import random

text = "Проверка {Ваня|Петя|Таня} работы {1|2|3|4|5} вского"

blocks = re.findall(r"\{(.*?)\}", text)

res = text
for block in blocks:
    value = random.choice(block.split('|'))
    res = re.sub(r"\{(.*?)\}", value, res, 1)

print(res)
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не могу знать, что именно написанно в фигурных скобках. 
Там могут быть любые слова.
А я не знаю как их вытащить от туда(

Comment: а разве второй пример у меня не показывает как вытащить слова или там какие-то еще сложности?

Comment: Вы меня совершенно не понимаете. 
Возможно данный пример будет более понятен:

```
text = input('Введите текст: ') # {Добрый день|Добрый вечер} {Евгений|Дмитрий}
print(text.format(random.choice(object.split('|'))))
```

Comment: все равно не понял :), еще раз перечитал вопрос и тоже не понял. Т.е. вы вводите готовый текст внутри которого содержатся списки слов из которых должен произойти выбор? например `{a|b|c} привет` и программа должна в строке найти эти `{a|b|c}`, выделить их из строки, разбить на слова, выбрать отдельное слово и заменить в первоначальной строке?

Comment: Дааааааа, вы поняли меня!!! Вы просто супер! Осталось только помочь мне разобраться как это сделать(

Comment: делать надо через регулярные выражения (как один из вариантов) - я привел пример в конце своего ответа - посмотрите